# FFmpegWrapper - get exact segment start or end times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Right now, I'm using [FFmpegWrapper](https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper), and I watch for changes via kernel events. This gets the segments when they're created, but I'm not sure how accurate this is.

Really, I want to know the presentation timestamp of when the hls segment is created. Right now I capture and encode frames manually and write packets via 
`FFOutputFile *outputFile;`
`[_outputFile writePacket:_packet error:&error];`

So I have each frame's presentationTimestamp, but I don't know which frame goes to which eventual MPEG-TS segment. Once I write to the FFOutputFile, it's a blackbox to me.

Is there any way to know what frame will go to what segment ahead of time, or get a callback from FFmpeg when a new segment is written?

Exact times are ideal. Close times are better. Watching the directory for new files via kernel events is what I have right now, so any solution of that time magnitude isn't useful.